# NameError: global name 'deployment_mode' is not defined

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python. This is part of a larger codebase.
It has worked in the past, but recently started complaining.

I am calling `test.py` like this:

```
python -c "import test; test._register_cassandra_service(True)"
```

It's legacy code and has worked well in the past. It looks odd to me as

```
print('jjj')
```

was never executed, so `deployment_mode` is never initialized.

The code is as follows:

**test.py**

```
import os

def _register_cassandra_service(isReRegister):
    print('hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh')
    print(deployment_mode)

def main():
   global deployment_mode
   print('jjj')
   deployment_mode = os.environ.get('DEPLOY_MODE')
```

**Error**

```
ubuntu@vikdevtest-deploy:/opt/cisco/vms-installer/scripts$ python -c "import test; test._register_cassandra_service(True)"
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 5, in _register_cassandra_service
    print(deployment_mode)
NameError: global name 'deployment_mode' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `main()` doesn't run automatically. If you need it run, you need to call it.

Comment: @khelwood any idea how it worked earlier

Comment: @Chris_vr: you called `main()` explicitly or didn't put it in a function? `main()` is never automatically called.

Comment: @Chris_vr: I can't emphasise this enough: the code posted here *can't have worked*, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has no concept of a `main()` function that is the entry point for a module. If you need the code in `main()` to *always* run, then either explicitly call that function or move the code in it to the global namespace.

You can use a `__name__ == '__main__'` test to only run code when your module is used as a script (as the script file run by Python is internally given the module name `'__main__'`), but that doesn't apply here as you are running a `-c` script instead.

The code, as posted, could never have worked before now either. If you ever invoked it directly with `python test`, then look for a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to see what code is run there; that code *won't* run when you import the script with `import test`.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `main()` first before calling `_register_cassandra_service()`, so that the value of `deployment_mode` is set.

You can also call `main()` in `_register_cassandra_service()`, since it depends on `main()`.